# Running java agents in lotus notes

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Hi I am using lotus notes 8.5 and in view -> Agents i created a new Agent and selected java language and tried to test the basic running of the Agent.

```
import lotus.domino.*;

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

    public void NotesMain() {

        try {
            Session session = getSession();
            AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();

            System.out.println("Sample Test of Lotus Notes Agent!");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

so basically the above code must print in the java debugging console as "Sample Test of Lotus Notes Agent!" but it doesn't work.

BTW it is triggered to run at "After new mail has arrived" also i don't have Domino designer client. I must somehow make it work in lotus notes itself(cannot install any other tools like eclipse..)

EDIT: like i have mentioned in the comments i even tried to schedule and also tried event triggers but this doesn't work but i can manually run the agent by selecting "RUN" from the menu.

Thank You!

Comment: As Per said the agent runs on server not client. Do you really need it to run on client?

Comment: Yes!, when a new mail arrives in my inbox i want the agent to run in my system(i.e. client).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add LotusScript code to `Queryrecalc` event of the Inbox folder. That way the code will run on client when Inbox is refreshed. You can also start a Java agent from this LotusScript code.

Another possibility is to replicate the mail databases to client and run even based or scheduled background agents there.

Comment: yeah i tried this (File->replication->new replica) but when i try these settings (Server=local, file path = mail\MyID.nsf) and click OK it says that "database is currently in use"!!! i can run these agent in my local machine manually but i cant seem to get it run on trigger or scheduled events :/

Comment: Where are placing this setting "file path = mail\MyID.nsf"?

Comment: in here (File->replication->new replica) you get a dialog box.

Comment: its set there by default.

Comment: i am trying this part which you have said "Another possibility is to replicate the mail databases to client and run even based or scheduled background agents there"

Comment: Sounds like you already have the local replica, or at least copy with the same name.

Comment: what should i do now... :/ i thought some settings with replicate will solve my issue

Comment: Check if your mail\MyID.nsf is a replica (Database properties -> replica ID). If not then delete it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41878/discussion-between-wenn32-and-panu-haaramo)

Answer (score 3):

An "After new mail has arrived" agent is run by the Agent Manager server task - on the server and not on the client. If you have the required access to run agents on the server, you should see the result of the System.out.println() in the log file on the server (log.nsf).

Comment: how can i make it run on every mail received from client side??

Comment: If I recall correctly, the "After new mail has arrived" trigger is not guaranteed to run immediately after the message arrives because it needs an available Agent Manager thread, and it also needs the Agent Manager to check for mailboxes with new messages.  It will usually run within one or two minutes, but also because the Agent Manager imposes a minimum time of one or two minutes in between running the same agent in the same database file.

Comment: If you want a guarantee that the agent runs once for every single email, then you need to set it to run "Before new mail arrives". That type of agent is executed by the Router task, and therefore it does not have to wait for an available Agent Manager thread to become free.

Comment: where do you learn these stuffs!!!  can you please point me to a source :)   having a hard time finding sources

Comment: I also tried setting the trigger as "Before new mail arrives" but still it doesn't show any text in java debugger console window and yeah i received mails.