# Listening to Lotus Notes event (sent mail) with OLE (using Delphi)

Tags: delphi, events, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, ole

I want to build an application that is listening to the "sent mail" event of Lotus Notes and process the sent mail.

I am developing that with Delphi and since there is nothing else out there I guess I am stuck with using OLE (already using OLE to access selected mail from Lotus Notes and processing it).

So, is there a way to subscribe to some of the events of Lotus Notes and get the appropriate data using OLE ? (in this particular case, I would like to subscribe to the "sent mail" event, and get the mail document). I am also open to suggestions if somebody, with more Lotus Notes experience,  knows some other way of doing that, but in the end I have to access the mail with Delphi.

The application should run on the client machine and not on the server.

Thanks

Comment: By OLE, I presume you mean *COM*. OLE has been dead for ages. Google *Lotus Notes automation*, which will get you to the functionality Notes exposes to external apps. Prep for a nightmare of documentation not matching actual implementation, though.

Comment: Lotus supports both COM and OLE classes. The COM classes are rooted at lotus.NotesSession, and the OLE classes are rooted at Notes.NotesSession and Notes.NotesUIWorkspace. The OLE classes require that the Notes client is running - and will start it if it is not. The COM classes do not require that the Notes client is running, but do require that it must be installed and configured.

Comment: And event listening is possible with OLE ? Do you have any example code on that ?

Comment: No, there is no event interface in the OLE or COM classes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to do this client-side. Unfortunately, there is no way to subscribe to Notes client events via the OLE or COM interfaces provided in Notes and Domino. The only way to do that is with the [Notes C API](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/capi-nd/)'s [Extenstion Manager](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/tools/c/7.0/api70ug.nsf/85255d56004d2bfd85255b1800631684/06fd173414dcdad9852560eb0077ca42) interface, but this is really low-level stuff that requires extensive knowledge of Notes.

There is, however, a ready-made piece of code built with the Extension Manager called [TriggerHappy](https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Trigger%20Happy), which is available as open source on the OpenNTF site. It allows you to configure it to invoke LotusScript agents that are triggered by events. That (somewhat) lowers the learning curve around this.

Comment: Very useful to know, +1

Comment: Thank you for the information but I guess the effort is too big for the gain :). I will try MartyA effort reading the sent folder periodically and checking for mails that have my flag. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the COM interface to Lotus Notes is pretty well documented, maybe because it has been owned by IBM for over a decade.  You'll find one way into it here:http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ACCESSING_THE_DOMINO_OBJECTS_THROUGH_COM.html.

For Delphi, you'll need to create an import unit, Domino_Tlb.Pas for Notes' COM interface; it's a while since I did it but I think you do that by using Delphi's TypeLib Importer on the Notes NlsXbe.Dll, which is part of both the Notes client and server installs.

AFAIR, Notes' COM support doesn't expose any COM events though, so there is no support for "subscriptions" in the sense of an outbound, event-driven interface.  However, it is a commonplace with Notes to use its VB-like LotusScript language to write "agents" which can monitor mailfiles to trigger whatever actions are appropriate to whatever the business requirement happens to be.  Because there are no "events", agents implemented using the COM interface these have to work by periodically polling the Notes database of interest, and there are functions available to search for previously-unprocessed mail items (sent or arrived).  For instance, you could poll a Notes db's Inbox with code like this:

```
  View := DB.GetView('($Inbox)');
  Res := View.FTSEARCH('FIELD PostedDate < ''01/05/2012'' or FIELD DeliveredDate < ''01/05/2012''', 0);

  Doc := View.GetFirstDocument;
  Done := Doc <> Nil;
  while not Done do begin
    vFrom := Doc.GetItemValue('INetFrom');
    [...]
    Doc := View.GetNextDocument(Doc);
    if Doc = Nil then
      Done := True;
  end;
```

**Update:**  Agents written in LotusScript have access to a built-in collection `UnprocessedDocuments` that is unique to an individual agent so it can tell whether it has already processed a document (see http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/lotusscript/lotusscript.nsf/1efb1287fc7c27388525642e0074f2b6/fa9dc4724dab0fed8525642e007702d6?OpenDocument).  I don't recollect whether this would work for a COM agent, but I doubt it would matter if it didn't because a COM agent could always write a custom Item of its own to a document to indicate that it had processed it.

ISTR that it could be fairly irksome to find out what Notes fields are used for which purpose.
Working with Notes documents using the COM interface is pretty straightforward and when I was doing this sort of stuff a decade ago, I never came across any insurmountable hurdles to what I needed to do.

I doubt whether most Notes administrators would permit doing this sort of stuff on the Notes server, but it all works fine from a client machine and because of the built-in db replication support, you can do it either on the server version of the db or a local replica.

Essentially the same functionality as in LotusScript is available through the COM interface.

I'm afraid it had slipped my mind that you can install Java agents on the Domino server - see e.g. [Running java agents in lotus notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093318/running-java-agents-in-lotus-notes).  At my firm, we eliminated that as a possibility very early on because of the chaos-creating potential of a misbehaving agent on a live enterprise mail server.

Comment: As I said, I am already working with COM and accesing Lotus Notes Session. So you are basically telling me that I have to this subscription stuff in LotusScript and then import that code inside Delphi or how to get to access the mail from within Delphi after I identify it with LotusScript ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you'd already started.  Anyway, no, I mentioned LotusScript only because that's the way agents are usually coded and most of the documentation talks in terms of implementing them using LS.  Personally, I never came across anything that could be done in LS that couldn't also be done via COM.

Comment: thats at least "semi good" news :). But do you have a  link to some code about those agents ?

Comment: Not specifically, I found the only reference I ever needed was this book:https://www.amazon.co.uk/Lotus-Domino-Essential-Reference-ReferenceSeries/dp/0735700079/ref=sr_1_12?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1484905376&sr=1-12&keywords=lotus+notes and the LotusScript online manual.

Comment: Btw, I no longer have Notes available to check, but istr that there was a LotusScript manual amongst the online help that comes with the Notes client install.

Comment: When executing this piece of code View := DB.GetView('($Inbox)'); does that sent items folder need to be open inside lotus notes ? Maybe I could do this, and checking the folder periodically for my own flags and then process the mail ...

Comment: No, the classes in Domino_Tlb.Pas don't require the gui client to be running.  The Domino COM system does require a valid Username and Password but you can supply both of those in code. "Maybe I could do this ..."  Indeed.